# Why dynamic casting throw exception?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I have a enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second
}
```

I could cast int to Enum:

```
var sample1 = (MyEnum)1;
```

But i got exception on dynamic convertion with this:

```
var sample2 = System.Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(MyEnum));
//Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+MyEnum'.
```

Why dynamic casting throw exception?

I'm not looking for a solution and just like to know why the exception is thrown?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: 
Convert.ChangeType can only convert built-in types to a pre-defined set of classes. In the case of Int32, this is the same set of explicit classes as allowed by [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3k113cd.aspx).

**Long answer**:
Under the hood, the Convert.ChangeType method will call [Int32.IConvertible.ToType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350521.aspx).

This will in turn call the internal method `Convert.DefaultToType` which will work through a pre-defined list of types and call the appropriate method from IConvertible (e.g. if you requested a DateTime, it will call [ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.todatetime.aspx)). However, there is an interesting one in there from your point of view:

```
if (targetType == Convert.EnumType)
{
    return (Enum)value;
}
```

Which you might think would allow your code to work. However, it won't - the type of your enum is not [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) - it is a subclass of that.

Comment: What's your idea: if(targetType.IsEnum) (Enum)Enum.ToObject(targetType, value)?

Comment: @RezaArab This is framework code - you can't modify it. I was just explaining why the exception is thrown.